# How to use python split?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have some data like that:

[image]

I use split function process data into list.I want to make some data mining in this training set,but I don't know how to separate data as futures like this in python:

[image]

By the way,some data are float.Firstly,I want to fill all the data into a list,coding like that:

```
key_zi = []
for i in range(len(train_set['zi_id'])):
    key_zi = key_zi + train_set['zi_id'][i].split('/')
```

but the result call:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: post the raw input data and you're desired outcome

Comment: In Python, the formatting is `'\\'.split(text_to_split)`, not `text_to_split.split('\\')`

Comment: I find that document shows the formatting is `str.split(str="", num=string.count(str))`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I'm not the desired outcome, and I don't think the OP is either...

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do since no detail of raw data (file format, structure, etc.) and your code. Anyway, `if type(train_set['zi_id'][i]) != float:` would help.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the documentation says

```
str.split(str="", num=string.count(str))
```

What you're missing is that the the first instance of `str` in this definition is the delimiter for splitting.

Your error is that in this:

```
  train_set['zi_id'][i].split('/')
```

You are trying to call the `split` method of `train_set['zi_id'][i]`.   But that thing is a float, not a delimiter string.

Comment: You're welcome.  At StackOverflow the appropriate way to thank an answerer is to upvote the answer and `accept` it, by clicking the tick.